# .NET multi target Nuget

Tags: nuget, csproj

I am building a Nuget targeting *.NET 4.5.2* and *4.7.2* Hence I have used Multi Target in the **csproj** file(uses Microsoft.NET.Sdk for project template), and I have used *GeneratePackageOnBuild* to generate NuGet on build , the dotnet build work fine in local machine where dll is created in net452 and net472 sub directories in the Nuget. and I can refer the nuget in my application(4.5.2) and works fine, But  When I use Azure DevOps pipelines , build and package works fine and NuGet also contains both net452 and net472 But it seems both folder contains the same DLL(seems 472) and hence when I use the NuGet produced by AzureDevOps my consumer application fails to build. Why does the local build produces correct dlls and the AzureDevOps produces wrong dll's , I have a self hosted agent which have the same version of the  Visual studio  installed in my local machine